# QStandardItemModel get model of a child

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditemmodel

I am a beginner with Qt programming and I have a small problem. 
In fact, I have big `QStandardItemModel` on which I need to find some specific items with keywords. The idea is to let the user give two inputs, one for the country and another for the city. Once the country is found,the city has to be searched only under the matching countries. But the underlying code, it keep searching on the whole tree model.

To get the Matching countries, I do:

```
foundCountriesList = TreeModel->findItems(countryKeyword, 
    Qt::MatchStartsWith | Qt::MatchFixedString | Qt::MatchRecursive, 0);
```

Then I need to find the `city` Keyword only inside the matching country:

```
if (!foundCountriesList.isEmpty())
{
    foreach(QStandardItem* item, foundCountriesList)
    {
        foundCitiesList = item->child(0,0)->Model()->findItems(cityKeyword, 
            Qt::MatchStartsWith | Qt::MatchFixedString | 
            Qt::MatchRecursive, 0);
    }
}
```

But, it keeps searching for the `city` in the whole `TreeModel` because whenever I do `TreeModel->Item(0,0)->child(0,0)->Model()`, I always get `TreeModel` back.

Could anyone kindly give me some hints?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your tree structure? Are city items children of corresponding country item?

Comment: You have one model, that's why `model()` always return the same. Btw, your `if (!foundCountriesList.isEmpty())` is needless. `item->child(0,0)->model()->` is same as `TreeModel->`.

Comment: @Dimitry Sazonov : ok, but is there any method to build or extract a sub model out of this unique big model?

Comment: @AndySankarley you should subclass [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) and reimplement [`filterAcceptRow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) method. Or just create a new model from desired items. By hands, without any `findItems` calls

Comment: @vahancho : yes, Actually, each country node contains cities nodes and so on.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov : could you write a short example of how to implement  this please?

Comment: @AndySankarley [I can, but](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) I think that you should try it by yourself. And ask a question, if you have a problem. You should start with documentation, there are good examples inside. Links are in my upper comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it in the following way:

```
QStandardItem *findCityItem(const QString &city, const QString &country)
{
  auto cityItems = TreeModel->findItems(city,
                                        Qt::MatchRecursive | Qt::MatchWrap | Qt::MatchExactly, 0);
  for (auto cityItem : cityItems)
  {
    auto parent = item->parent();
    if (parent && (parent->data().toString() == country))
    {
      return item;
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

i.e. search for the city name and if cities are found, check to which country they belong to.

Comment: Thank you, That would have worked but actually TreeModel is a really a big object, containing a lot of children and children of children. To make such a research with a city takes to much time, and that's why I need him to search only under a specific country.

Comment: I see, but to search under a specific country you need to find that country first.

Comment: To find countries I just did:                                            
  foundCountriesList = TreeModel->findItems(countryKeyword, 
    Qt::MatchStartsWith | Qt::MatchFixedString, 0);                                                     And this works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already loop through all items with desired country, you can filter out the city yourself, by examining items' values.

You can also try using [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). Make one to filter out by country (it's source will be your main model), and another one to filter out by city (it's source will be the proxy model for countries).